# If $ \lambda'(t) \in {\rm Span}(v)$ then $\lambda(t)$ belongs to a straight line

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

If $\lambda:(a,b)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a path differentiable (not necessarily of class $C^1$) where $\displaystyle \lambda'(t)\in {\rm Span}(v)$. How to prove that $\lambda(t)$ belongs to a straight line.

$\displaystyle {\rm Span}(v)=\{t\cdot v:t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ , $||v||=1$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $x,y$ be two linearly independent vectors orthogonal to $v$. Consider $X(t) = \langle x, \lambda(t)\rangle$ and $Y(t) = \langle y, \lambda(t)\rangle$. What can you say about $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Fix some number $c\in (a,b)$. Let's show that $\lambda(t)-\lambda(c)\in\text{span}(v)$.

By absurd, suppose this is not true. Then there exists some $t_0$ such that $\lambda(t_0)-\lambda(c)\not\in\text{span}(v)$. Take any linear function $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $T(v)=0$ and $T(\lambda(t_0)-\lambda(c))\neq 0$, that is, $T(\lambda(t_0))\neq T(\lambda(c))$. Then the function $T\circ\lambda$ is differentiable, and
$$(T\circ\lambda)'(t)=T(\lambda'(t))=0.$$
Hence, $T\circ\lambda$ is constant, an absurd.

This shows that $\lambda(t)\in\lambda(c)+\text{span}(v)$ for every $t$, which is a straigth line.

(This argument can be adapted to more general spaces, such as locally convex Hausdorff TVS's, using Hahn-Banach)

Answer (score 1):

Make a linear change of coordinates so that $v=(1,0)$. If $\lambda=(x,y)$ than $y'=0$, hence is constant.